# Magento Display Dynamic SKU for configurable Product... Don't Display until all options are selected

Tags: javascript, php, magento, dynamic

So I just found [this code](http://www.unchi.co.uk/2012/03/14/displaying-and-changing-a-sku-on-a-magento-product-page/) that does what I want, almost.  I need for the code to dynamically display the sku of a configurable product (simple product's sku) when the options are selected.  The only problem is that until the options are selected, it shows the first simple product sku.  I want it to show nothing until all the options are selected.

Here is the code:
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Skus =new Array();

<?php
$count = 1;
$itemId = array();
foreach($col as $simple_product){
$itemId[] = array($simple_product->getSelectLabel() => $simple_product->getSku());
}

foreach($itemId as $val){
foreach($val as $k => $v){
echo 'Skus['.$count.'] = "'.$v.'";'. "\n";
$count++;
}
};

?>

$j(document).ready(function(){

$j("#productcode").html("Product Code: " +Skus[1]);

$j("select#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>").change(function(){
var position = $j("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?> option").index($j("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?> option:selected"));

$j("#productcode").html(Skus[position] ? "Product Code: " +Skus[position] : "Product Code: " +Skus[1]);
});

});

</script>
```

And:
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/view.phtml

```
<div id="productcode"></div>
```

Currently, the dynamic sku shows the first sku record until all the options are selected and then shows the correct one.  How can I hide the sku until all options are selected or hide it if someone goes back to edit their selections?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment (or remove) the following line it won't put anything in the div onload:

```
$j("#productcode").html("Product Code: " +Skus[1]);
```

The following code will still write the SKU there when the select is changed:

```
$j("select#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>").change(function(){
var position = $j("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?> option").index($j("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?> option:selected"));

$j("#productcode").html(Skus[position] ? "Product Code: " +Skus[position] : "Product Code: " +Skus[1]);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I remove the suggested line, nothing displays.  Do I need to add the 2nd piece of code?  If yes, where?

Comment: Actually, The 2nd piece of code is already part of the original code... are any changes required for this code?  If yes, where and what?